# Mistake in fourier series

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

I've the following function $\text{U}\left(t\right)$ that is defined as posted in the picture:

[image]

My book tells me that the Fourier series looks like:

$$\tag{1}U(t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2 \hat{u} \dfrac{\tau}{T}\dfrac{\sin(\dfrac12 n \omega \tau)}{\dfrac12 n \omega \tau}\cos(n \omega t-\dfrac12 n \omega \tau) \ \ \ \text{with} \ \ \omega:=\dfrac{2 \pi}{T}.$$

Now, I used Mathematica to plot the function given by formula $(1)$ but I got something else (I set some values for the constants in the function and plot it for $t$) so not the thing I was supposed to get.

> Where is the mistake in the series?

Comment: would you mind to include the picture directly and describe it properly?

Comment: I can not I've not enougth +

Comment: i uploaded the picture for you, but now it is your turn to give a proper description

Comment: What is $\omega$? What is the $x$-coordinate of the first square wave?

Comment: I have done it. But something is missing : picture 2.

Comment: @JeanMarie Picture 2 was the function. and $\omega=\frac{2\pi}{\text{T}}$

Comment: I have modified your text that is now OK (I think so...)

Comment: What did Mathematica tell you ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust A different kind of plot more like a symmetric blocksignal

Comment: No, I mean what did you input and what did it output ? As a rule of thumbs, the book is right and you wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understanding that $\omega=2*\pi /T$, then the formula in the book is just missing the constant term ${\hat u\,\frac{\tau }{T}}$.
The correct formula is in fact:
$$u(t) = \hat u\,\frac{\tau }{T} + \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,n} {2\,\hat u\,\frac{\tau }{T}\frac{{\sin \frac{1}{2}n\,\omega \,\tau }}{{\frac{1}{2}n\,\omega \,\tau }}} \cos \left( {n\,\omega \,t - \frac{1}{2}n\,\omega \,\tau } \right)
$$

*p.s.:*
with the further understanding that the function actually be: 
$$
u(t)\quad \left| {\;0 \le t < T} \right.\quad  = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {\,\hat u} & {0 \le t < \tau }  \\
   0 & {\tau  \le t < T}  \\
\end{array}} \right.
$$
i.e. that the step starts from $t=0$, which from the picture is not so evident

Comment: So it is right but I've to add: $\hat u\,\frac{\tau }{T}$?

Comment: @asdasd: yes, in fact